# Error: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, terraform

I am trying to create a docker/posgresql infrastrucure with terraform:
I used the examples in the terraform_postgres_provider

```
+--modules
|   +--docker
    |  +--main.tf
|   +--postgres
    |  +--main.tf
+--root.tf
```

this is the code for moduels/docker/main.tf

```
variable "name" {
  default = "postgres"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "2.19.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {
  host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
}

resource "docker_image" "postgres" {
  name = "postgres:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "postgres" {
  image    = "${docker_image.postgres.latest}"
  name     = "${var.name}"
  restart  = "always"
  hostname = "${var.name}"
  env=[ "host=localhost","port=5432","POSTGRES_USER=postgres","POSTGRES_PASSWORD:123456"]
  ports {
    internal = "5432"
    external = "5432"
  }
}
```

this is the code for moduels/postgres/main.tf

```
variable "name" {
  default = "postgres"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    postgresql = {
      source = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = "1.16.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "postgresql" {
  alias           = "pg1"
  # host            = "${var.name}" // will not work because 'postgres' is only resolved within the docker dns
  host            = "localhost"
  port            = 5432
  username        = "postgres"
  password        = "123456"
  sslmode         = "disable"
  connect_timeout = 15
}

resource "postgresql_database" "mutualfunds" {
  provider = postgresql.pg1
  name     = "mutualfunds"
}
```

this is the code for root.tf

```
module "docker" {
  source = "./modules/docker"
  name   = "postgres"
}

module "postgres" {
  source = "./modules/postgres"
  name   = "postgres"
}
```

I got the error mentioned in the title above.

in docker the container log shows this error:

```
connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What is it actually you are trying to achieve?

Comment: TF really is not a very good tool for managing containers.

Comment: @jordanm could please share the best tool to manage containers.

Comment: @Marko E I am trying to make a docker container for a postgres server. would you explain what is clear in the error becasue I provide the password for the user.

Comment: If you take a look on Docker Hub what are the requirements when running a PostgreSQL container, you will see that environment variables are required.

Comment: @MarkoE  I checked the inspect tap on the docker container that TF created and all postgres config parameters where set to the values I specified in the TF source